# How to add foreign key in db_schema.xml

Tags: magento2.3, upgradeschema, declarative-schema, database-schema

I'm using magento 2.3 to create a custom module, i tried to create database tables for my custom module in `etc/db_schema.xml` like this:

```
<table comment="province Table" engine="innodb" name="province" resource="default">
    <column comment="Entity Id" identity="true" name="province_id" nullable="false" padding="6" unsigned="false" xsi:type="smallint"/>
    <constraint referenceId="PRIMARY" xsi:type="primary">
        <column name="province_id"/>
    </constraint>
    <column length="255" name="name" nullable="true" xsi:type="varchar"/>
</table>
<table comment="City Table" engine="innodb" name="city" resource="default">
    <column comment="Entity Id" identity="true" name="city_id" nullable="false" padding="6" unsigned="false" xsi:type="smallint"/>
    <constraint referenceId="PRIMARY" xsi:type="primary">
        <column name="city_id"/>
    </constraint>
    <column name="province_id" nullable="true" xsi:type="integer"/>
    <column length="255" name="name" nullable="true" xsi:type="varchar"/>
    <column length="255" name="type" nullable="true" xsi:type="varchar"/>
</table>
```

There are two new tables **province** and **city**.  Here `province_id` field is the primary key of **province** table. I also put the `province_id` field in **city** table, but for now, that field does not refer as a foreign key to **province** table, how can I make the `province_id` in **city** table a foreign key that refers to **province** table `province_id`?

Answer (score 6):

**here is solution of your problem**

```
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table comment="province Table" engine="innodb" name="province" resource="default">
        <column comment="Entity Id" identity="true" name="province_id" nullable="false" padding="6" unsigned="false" xsi:type="smallint"/>
        <column length="255" name="name" nullable="true" xsi:type="varchar"/>

        <constraint referenceId="PRIMARY" xsi:type="primary">
            <column name="province_id"/>
        </constraint>
    </table>

    <table comment="City Table" engine="innodb" name="city" resource="default">
        <column comment="Entity Id" identity="true" name="city_id" nullable="false" padding="6" unsigned="false" xsi:type="smallint"/>
        <column comment="Province id" identity="false" name="province_id" nullable="false" padding="6" unsigned="false" xsi:type="smallint"/>
        <column length="255" name="name" nullable="true" xsi:type="varchar"/>
        <column length="255" name="type" nullable="true" xsi:type="varchar"/>

        <constraint referenceId="PRIMARY" xsi:type="primary">
            <column name="city_id"/>
        </constraint>

        <constraint xsi:type="foreign" referenceId="PROVINCE_PROVINCE_ID_CITY_PROVINCE_ID" table="city" column="province_id" referenceTable="province" referenceColumn="province_id"/>
    </table>
</schema>
```

Answer (score 2):

[Try to use existing cms module as an example](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Cms/etc/db_schema.xml#L41):

```
<constraint xsi:type="foreign" referenceId="CMS_BLOCK_STORE_STORE_ID_STORE_STORE_ID" table="cms_block_store"
                column="store_id" referenceTable="store" referenceColumn="store_id" onDelete="CASCADE"/>
```

Note: make sure both table column that you want to add as a key, have same property. Ex: Both column type, size etc. should same.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer [Devdocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/db-schema.html)

```
<constraint xsi:type="foreign" name="COMPANY_CREDIT_COMPANY_ID_DIRECTORY_COUNTRY_COUNTRY_ID" table="company_credit" column="company_id" referenceTable="company" referenceColumn="entity_id" onDelete="CASCADE"/>
```